# How to get the difference between previous and current node inner text value

Tags: xml, xslt

Would you please help me on this.  I would like to insert a node to every node. This node is contain the difference between "OriIndex" of this node and the "OriIndex" of previous node (just one before this).  I have a compile error when writing my XSLT.

My Input is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <Test>
    <TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>1</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>1</TestParameter>
    <OriIndex>0</OriIndex>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>1</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>2</TestParameter>
    <OriIndex>1</OriIndex>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>3</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>1</TestParameter>
    <OriIndex>2</OriIndex>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>2</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>2</TestParameter>
    <OriIndex>3</OriIndex>
  </Test>
```

My XML output is (This one is wrong because the Diff of second item should be 1 = Current OriIndex (1) - previous OriIndex (0).  Actually I have no idea how to do this) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <Test>
    <TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>1</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>1</TestParameter>
    <OriIndex>0</OriIndex>
    <SortedIndex>0</SortedIndex>
    <Diff>1</Diff>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <TestPhase>1</TestPhase>
    <TestFlow>1</TestFlow>
    <TestParameter>2</TestParameter>
    <OriIndex>1</OriIndex>
    <SortedIndex>1</SortedIndex>
    <Diff>0</Diff>
  </Test>
.
.
.
.
```

My XSLT is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding = "UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" standalone="yes" />


  <xsl:template match="Root">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Test">
      <xsl:sort select="TestPhase" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="TestFlow" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:sort select="TestParameter" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


   <xsl:template match="Test">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/> 
       <SortedIndex><xsl:value-of select="position() - 1"/></SortedIndex>
       <Diff><xsl:value-of select="OriIndex - OriIndex[position() - 1]" /></Diff>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help.

Thank you very much.  Your effort is very much appreciated.

Cheers !

Comment: Please show the input and the expected output .

Comment: Dear Michael, many thanks.  I have done the corrections.  Please advice.

Comment: When you say "previous node", do you mean after sorting? If yes, you will have to do this in two passes.

Comment: Thanks Michael H I am using the new XSLT but there are still some modification needed. Please help.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This node [should] contain the difference between "OriIndex" of this node and the "OriIndex" of previous node (just one before this).

An XPath expression for the `<OriIndex>` child of the preceding sibling of the context node (equivalent to the preceding sibling *element*, because only elements and the document root can have element children) would be

```
preceding-sibling::*[1]/OriIndex
```

For your particular data and context, you might write instead this more explicit expression:

```
preceding-sibling::Test[1]/OriIndex
```

Overall, then, you might put that together into this template:

```
    <xsl:template match="Test">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/> 
        <SortedIndex><xsl:value-of select="position() - 1"/></SortedIndex>
        <Diff><xsl:value-of
            select="OriIndex - preceding-sibling::Test[1]/OriIndex" /></Diff>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks John Bollinger.  I am not able to get the inner value of incremental previous OriIndex.  I have tryout your method.   But it is lock to [1] and it becomes NaN when I use [position()-1] .   Please help.  Thank you very much John Bollinger.  Cheers !

Comment: May I know if I can do this without foreach loop ?  Thanks in advance.  Cheers!

Comment: Well yes, @newbuntu, naturally you get NaN for the first `<Test>`, because it has no preceding sibling.  The formula you asked about is not defined there.  For other nodes in your example data you always get a `<Diff>` of 1 because that follows from your data.  Note in particular that all of this is necessarily based on the order of the *input* document, not the output.  That's how XSLT works.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is It possible to change [1] to something that changes or a variable which follows the position? Let's say, if I use foreach loop to do it, is it possible?  Please help.  Thank you very much.  Cheers !

Comment: A couple of Thank you again for you.  I am able to produce it using the method you suggested, with [1].  I save the file and then create  another XSLT to add in the DiffOriIndex I wanted.  The XML produce is same as my expected XML.  Thanks you very much John Bollinger.  Your method is really help and good. Cheers !